# Rails 3 Admin Section Design Question About Inheritance and Namespacing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, namespaces, admin

The way my site operates, some records are created by the user but are only partially filled out. An administrator has to complete some of the record fields. I was thinking about putting all the validations related to the administrative fields in a subclass.

For example, in `/app/models/document.rb`:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  # minimal validations needed, etc
end
```

In `/app/models/admin/document.rb` (I'm not even sure if the syntax below is valid Ruby)

```
class Admin::Document < Document
  # Extra validations for the fields the admin
end
```

Would my approach be a bad idea? I also plan on having role based authentications using something like CanCan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps an alternative route would be to use CanCan to allow admins to complete a users document but instead of subclassing the record or splitting it over two. When the form is submitted add an `administrated` ( or `approved` ) field then if its one admin or several you can search by the `unadministrated`( or `unapproved` )

Surely at the end of the day the admin does the final submission so they can then set the `administrated` ( or `approved` ) to true. Thereby finalizing the document?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be better to keep all of the validations in one class, and have a boolean database column that stores if the record has been completed by the administrator.

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :completed_by_administrator # do not allow this to be set via mass assignment
  validate ..., :if => :completed_by_administrator # only do these validates if completed_by_administrator is true
end
```

When the record is first created, `completed_by_administrator` is false and the admin-only validations do not run.  When the record is completed by an administrator, set `completed_by_administrator = true` in your controller and the admin-only validations automatically run before the record is saved.